# Can I perform an admin action without logging in?

Tags: wordpress, post, admin

let's say I want to trash a specific post.
Through the admin panel, if I hover over the "Trash" option, I get the following link:

https://domainname.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=17074&action=trash&_wpnonce=342f5a3db7

At the moment, if I use that link without being logged in, it says I don't have sufficient permissions to access that page.
I would like to be able to use that link without being logged in, is it possible to do so?
For instance, I would send that link by mail to someone who would just click on it without logging in.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Admin URLs can't access without login. To do such functionalities without login i suggest you to create custom page and pass the post ID in URL(may be in encrypted format to allow particular post) to update that post status TRASH.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have already created a page with the list of posts, each one with its relative clickable link, but the problem happens when I click on the link: the action cannot be performed because it requires admin permissions.

Comment: You mean you have admin URL to move posts into trash or your custom page link ? Can you please share the URL of that page ?